# How can I check if url_for references an existing file?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am serving pictures from a loop. Some of the referenced URL's do not exist though. In that case I want to reference to a default pic.

I tried

```
{% for hit in hits %}
{% if url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + hit['jpg']) %}
<img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + hit['jpg']) }}">
{% else %}
<img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + 'default.jpg') }}">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

which seemed to be a bit naive since it didn't change anything. Do you have an idea for a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always chose the right image path before rendering the template. So maybe something with [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile):

```py
import os
from Flask import render_template
...

for i in range(len(hits)):
    if not os.path.isfile('relative/path/to/pictures/' + hits[i]['jpg']):
        hits[i]['jpg'] = 'default.jpg' 

render_template('/my/template.html', hits = hits, ...)
```

Template:

```
{% for hit in hits %}
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'pictures/' + hit['jpg']) }}">
{% endfor %}
```